# How to split and move the column?

Tags: python

I rotate the table with transpose(). Then I check and change every element with transform() and transformer(). The problem is with transformer():
I divided the first row. The second part (phone numbers) stays in the first row. The first (names) part is moved to the third row. The problem is that I assign the first element of names to each element of the third row. How to assign the corresponding elements to the third row and if possible to remove the last two characters from the names?

```
from tabulate import tabulate

fio = []
def transformer(i, value):
    if i == 0:
        rev_val = value.split("|")
        fio.append([rev_val[0]])
        return rev_val[1]
    if i == 1:
        replaced = value.replace('@', '[at]')
        return replaced
    if i == 2:
        for column in range(len(fio)):
            return fio[column]

def transform(table):
    for i in range(len(table)):
        for j in range(len(table[i])):
            table[i][j] = transformer(i, table[i][j])
    return table

def transpose(table):
    response = []
    for i in range(len(table[0])):
        response.append([])
        for j in range(len(table)):
            response[i].append(table[j][i])
    return response

def main(table):
    return transform(transpose((table)))

table = [["Smith, О.А.|00-07-16", "cazirko51@yandex.ru", "cazirko51@yandex.ru"],
         ["Brian, С.Е.|12-07-15", "derli48@mail.ru", "derli48@mail.ru"],
         ["Henry, B.О.|01-12-16", "rakilman9@yahoo.com", "rakilman9@yahoo.com"],
         ["Bernard, M.О.|71-12-32", "gbfe9@yahoo.com", "gbfe9@yahoo.com"]]

print(tabulate(main(table)))
```

Output:

```
----------------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------------------
00-07-16                12-07-15            01-12-16                71-12-32
cazirko51[at]yandex.ru  derli48[at]mail.ru  rakilman9[at]yahoo.com  gbfe9[at]yahoo.com
['Smith, О.А.']         ['Smith, О.А.']     ['Smith, О.А.']         ['Smith, О.А.']
----------------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------------------
```

The correct output I want:

```
00-07-16                12-07-15            01-12-16                71-12-32
cazirko51[at]yandex.ru  derli48[at]mail.ru  rakilman9[at]yahoo.com  gbfe9[at]yahoo.com
Smith, О.               Brian, С.           Henry, B.               Bernard, M.
----------------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------------------
```

Comment: What is `tabulate()` - are you using `from tabulate import tabulate`? You mention phone numbers, but I see only dates, names and mail addresses? Why are you collecting the names in a list, and is the problem that all 4 appear to have `'Smith, O.,A.'` as their name, instead of the corresponding names?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and try to isolate the problem. What parts of the code seem to be working correctly? What parts don't? Also - can you please show, what should the output be instead, for this input? Or rather, what should be the input to `tabulate`?

Comment: All 4 appear to have `'Smith, O.,A.'` as their name is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but this feels a bit too complicated?

Couldn't you do just something like this:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [["Smith, О.А.|00-07-16", "cazirko51@yandex.ru", "cazirko51@yandex.ru"],
         ["Brian, С.Е.|12-07-15", "derli48@mail.ru", "derli48@mail.ru"],
         ["Henry, B.О.|01-12-16", "rakilman9@yahoo.com", "rakilman9@yahoo.com"],
         ["Bernard, M.О.|71-12-32", "gbfe9@yahoo.com", "gbfe9@yahoo.com"]]

table = (row[0].split("|") + [row[1].replace("@", "[at]")] for row in table)
table = ([row[1], row[2], row[0]] for row in table)
table = [list(row) for row in zip(*table)]

print(tabulate(table))
```

Output:

```
----------------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------------------
00-07-16                12-07-15            01-12-16                71-12-32
cazirko51[at]yandex.ru  derli48[at]mail.ru  rakilman9[at]yahoo.com  gbfe9[at]yahoo.com
Smith, О.А.             Brian, С.Е.         Henry, B.О.             Bernard, M.О.
----------------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------------------
```

Comment: This platform needs more solvers like you and fewer critics.